# Homebrew installation guidance

Tags: terminal, osx-mavericks, homebrew

I have extracted Homebrew tar file into "/usr/local/homebrew" directory. Now how do i make the terminal to use the command "brew" to do homebrew actions?

I am using mac os 10.9.3 with xcode installed already.

Answer (score 0):

i just did this and it worked  sudo ln -s /usr/local/homebrew/bin/brew /usr/local/bin/brew